# I am trying to create a new window and execute a function after that new window creation in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a new window in tkinter and then execute the function after that but the function gets executed first and then the new window pops up.

Here is the code snippet :

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

def loop():
   for i in range(5):
      time.sleep(1)
       print(i)

def new():
   new = tk.Toplevel(window)
   new.geometry("450x250")
   new.title('new window')
   tk.Label(new, text="new one").place(x=150, y=40)
   loop()

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("450x250")
window.title('main window')

button = tk.Button(window , text='button', width=20,command= new)
button.place(x=180,y=200)
window.mainloop()
```

numbers are printed from 1 to 9 and then the new window pops up.
Even if it requires destroying the main window, it's fine.
A little help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter has two universal widget methods that will help do what you want. One is called [`wait_visibility()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) which will pause the program until the new `Toplevel` is visible. The second is called `after()` which allows the scheduling of call to a function after a delay specified in milliseconds. If the called function does the same thing, effectively it creates a loop.

Here's how to use them:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

def loop(limit, i):
    if i < limit:
        print(i)
        window.after(1000, loop, limit, i+1)

def new():
    new = tk.Toplevel(window)
    new.geometry("450x250")
    new.title('new window')
    tk.Label(new, text="new one").place(x=150, y=40)
    window.wait_visibility(new)
    loop(5, 0)

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("450x250")
window.title('main window')

button = tk.Button(window, text='button', width=20, command=new)
button.place(x=180,y=200)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is the `window.wait_visibility(new)` needed? As soon as code execution goes back to `window.mainloop()`, the window will be shown.

Comment: @TheLizzard: I think so. It's needed to delay (and trigger) that initial call to the `loop()` function.

Comment: Even if you remove it, it shouldn't cause any changes to the GUI. Also in OP's code the program first sleeps then prints 0, so `window.after(1000, loop, 5, 0)` can be used to replace the `window.wait_visibility(new); loop(5, 0)`